# Improve performance of self join in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table with 21 columns (all integers) id, c1 , c2 ... c20 and what to fetch ids for rows that have the same values in the columns ...

so row 1 will match row 10 if row 1 c1 = row 10 c1 and row 1 c2 = row 10 c2 ... and so on.

This is what the query looks like:

```
 select r1.id, r2.id 
 from tbl r1, tbl r2  
 where 1=1 and r1.c1=r2.c1 and r1.c2=r2.c2 and 
         ..... r1.c20=r2.c20 and not r1.id=r2.id
```

I am currently using self join, but this is way too slow (20 secs for 10000 rows).
I have setup indexes on the columns (?)
I have ~ 1 million rows
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a single index on all 20 columns?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create an extra column, where you can store a hash of all the values in the row. Then simply index that column and filter the rows that match the hash of the 20 values you are searching for.

Comment: i will need to be able to do other queries (apologies for not stating this on the post) such as 

r1.c1-r2.c1 > min and r1.c1-r2.c1 < max and
r1.c2-r2.c2 > min and r1.c2-r2.c2 < max ....

for integer min and max = 1, 2, 3 ...

I am not sure how this can be done with hashes?

Comment: @paulN: No, this won't help then. By the way, do you have a separate index on each field, as Marcelo suggested?

Comment: Thanks for that ... it is now much better and only taking 0.2 seconds for the query against ~1 million rows! I created single index for all 20 columns as suggested.